Dissapearing bugs in 3d perspective
I just want to finish my 3d modeling of characters in different shapes and sizes but my user perspective shows nothing even though my outliner says I have 3 pictures in the viewport
Cat still frame but impossible to see due to viewport errors


Check the empty image's options, it could be set to not show up in perspective:


Check in your Overlays dropdown at the top to see if you may have inadvertently turned off "Extras." This will cause objects of various types to become hidden, including empties.

